# Sum unique properties in different collection elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am quite new to MongoDB. Hopefully I am using the correct terminology to express my problem.

I have the following collection:

```
Data collection
{
   "name":"ABC",
  "resourceId":"i-1234",
  "volumeId":"v-1234",
  "data":"11/6/2013 12AM",
  "cost": 0.5
},
{
  "name":"ABC",
  "resourceId":"v-1234",
  "volumeId":"",
  "data":"11/6/2013 2AM",
  "cost": 1.5
}
```

I want to query the collection such that if a `volumeId` matches with another entries `resourceId`, then sum up the corresponding `resourceId`'s cost together.

As a result, the cost would be `2.0` in this case. 
Basically I want to match the volumeId of one entry to the resourceId of another entry and sum the costs if matched.

I hope I have explained my problem properly. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: as I understand, you want to group documents by resource id where volume id = resource id, and for each group sum cost?

Comment: @ari will there be another document, with `volumeId` equal to `i-1234`? I mean if a document has `volumeId` is it possible that another document will have the `resourceId` of the first one as its `volumeId?`

Comment: @AntonPutau, yes exactly. I want to group documents where `volumeId` == `resourceId` by `resourceId`. Note that there exists multiple `resourceId: "i-1234"`.
 @n9code There will not be another document with `volumeId` equal to `i-1234`, or any association to `resourceId`.

Comment: So then, is this statement true? If a document has non-empty `volumeId` then there exists no other document that has `volumeId` with value of the first document's  `resourceId`?

Comment: @n9code, This is true. A `volumeId` can only be associated to one `resourceId`. However, the same `resourceId` with associated `volumeIds` and cost updates will be updated in the db every hour or so. Hope this is helping.

Comment: Checkout my answer, see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this aggregation query:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
                      resourceId: 1, 
                      volumeId: 1, 
                      cost: 1, 
                      match: {
                                 $cond: [
                                           {$eq: ["$volumeId", ""]}, 
                                           "$resourceId", 
                                           "$volumeId"
                                        ]
                             }
                   }
    }, 
    {
        $group: {
                    _id: '$match', 
                    cost: {$sum: '$cost'},
                    resId: {
                              $addToSet: {
                                            $cond: [
                                                      {$eq: ['$match', '$resourceId']}, 
                                                      null, 
                                                      '$resourceId'
                                                   ]
                                         }
                           }
                }
    }, 
    {$unwind: '$resId'},
    {$match: {
                resId: {
                          $ne: null
                       }
              }
    },
    {
        $project: {
                      resourseId: '$resId', 
                      cost: 1, 
                      _id: 0
                  }
    }
])
```

And you will get the following:

```
{ "cost" : 2, "resourseId" : "i-1234" }
```

This is assuming [the statement I wrote in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443725/sum-unique-properties-in-different-collection-elements#comment48971405_30443725) is true.

Comment: This is definitely a great help! Thank you. However I'm not sure how to modify this if I want to for example have  `{ "cost" : 2, "resourseId" : "i-1234" }` outputted instead of `v-1234`

Comment: Checkout the update. Somewhat _hacky_, but works in your conditions.